# The number of downloads of packages in packages' repositories

Tags: package, package-repositories

On [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/) website, the number of downloads of each package is given.

I am wondering if one can see this info within Emacs. It seems that the built-in package installer `list-package` does not provide this info.

I know the package [paradox](https://github.com/Malabarba/paradox/) can give the popularity of many packages on github.
I just interested in the numbers of downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paradox can show it

> paradox-display-download-count is a variable defined in
> `paradox-menu.el'. Its value is nil
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
> version 1.2.3 of the paradox package.
>
> Documentation: If non-nil, adds a "Download" column to the Package
> Menu.

You can also use the HTTP API (https://melpa.org/download_counts.json) directly, e.g.,

```
$ curl https://melpa.org/download_counts.json | jq .magit
2502996
```

Another choice is https://github.com/emacscollective/epkg via `M-x epkg-list-packages`, it shows GitHub stars and Melpa downloads out-of-box.

[image: screen shot of M-x epkg-list-packages]

Don't forget it's Melpa downloads count, other elpas such as gnu elpa does not have such info, and people sometimes use Melpa through Melpa mirrors, the downloads count is not included.

Comment: Ok `(setq paradox-display-download-count t)` can do the job.